# Is it possible to show action buttons in iOS Interactive Notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am curious to find out if I can show the action buttons in an iOS 8 Interactive Notification by default (i.e., without forcing the user to swipe or pull down to reveal them). Is this possible, even if C is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there isn't a way to do this (and for a good reason). It's probably part of apple's human interface guidelines because they don't want to make some big obtrusive view overshadow whatever you are working on. (I know that I get annoyed when a group chat is happening and I can't click anything on the top of the screen since it keeps popping up).

But it might be possible, although it would require hooking some methods in a jailbreak tweak, not in standard public API calls.